# Convert Datetime to just date

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash to move some documents from a database into elasticsearch. Some of these documents have a datetime and others only have a date, as the way the dates were being stored was changed. In logstash, I am trying to add a new field that will be just the date, without time, so I can be sure that certain searches will work the way I expect.

I have tried using the date filter and ruby filter to runa script, but both produce errors (in the case of the ruby filter, the event that you can manipulate apparently doesn't have any of the fields of the actual document).

The document  I am moving over looks something like this:

```json
{
    "id": "something"
    "type": "sometype"
    "datetime": some-da-teTso:me:ti.meZ
}
```

Comment: How about changing your field mapping to basic_date?  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: Won't that cause issues when the documents that do have times on them come in to elasticsearch?

Comment: From the way it reads, it throws away the time, which is how I read your original request.

Comment: Having tried it now, it throws an error and just doesn't index the ones that have times.